# An SDK Target must be specified. in eplipce and SDK android

Tags: android, sdk, target

I can not create a new project.

When I try to create a new project, I put the name and then I get

> An SDK Target must be specified.

Comment: But this comes up as just a warning. This should not stop you from building your project. Right?

Comment: You should probably specify an sdk target then

Answer (score 0):

There should be a [Checkbox list](http://media.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/08/Eclipse-Create-New-Android-Project.png) where all the Android Targets are specified, choose the one you want your application to be compatible with. It can be anything between Android 1.5 - Android 2.2

Hope that helps.

Comment: @Jay, If you find the answer satisfactory, please mark the green arrow, and mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a list of build targets further down the page. If this is empty, go to the SDK and AVD manager (android with a down arrow) and go to available packages and download one.